# Is a Unit with broken locks considered Unfit or in disrepair

Tags: rental-property, australia

I moved into a new unit, however, on arrival the front door lock was broken and can't be locked from the outside. There is a screen-door however, the wiring near the lock has been cut and it is easy to unlock the door from the outside.

In the contract, there is a section pertaining to the lessors obligations that says:

```
(1) At the start of the tenancy, the lessors must ensure -
...
(B) the premises are fit for the tenant to live in; and
(C) the premises are in good repair; and
```

Can the doors not locking, be considered a breach of contract due to these two conditions? This would be in Australia, Queensland, Brisbane.

Comment: What jurisdiction is this in? What country, what state or province, and if possible what city or other local jurisdiction? Laws on such matters vary widely. The exact provisions of the lease will matter also.

Comment: The first recourse would be to complain to the management. If they fix the problem, ther probably is no legal, issue.

Comment: @davidsiegal, this would be in Australia, Queensland, Brisbane. The first recourse would be to complain, however, management already knew of the issue before I moved in. They notified me when I went to pickup my keys. I've called the emergency contact number listed, but no one answered. Mind you it was over a weekend.